# What protocol do scanners user to send image data over USB?

Tags: usb, protocols, file-transfer

I'm in the process of designing a piece of custom scanning hardware, and I'm wondering how traditional scanners (flatbed, film, etc), transfer image data over USB. I'm wondering if there is a particular protocol they use, or perhaps just a serial transfer?